# Appending Multiple Rows while updating from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function clearData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet");
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("2:21");
  var values = source_range.getValues();


  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kNzG4IQrI9TSlGzpIjp_84uWzoraVDSLPyAS-RIJPh4/edit#gid=1047694951");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Deposits");
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(2,1,values.length,values[19].length);// use the array size to define the range because the target column A is not necessarily the same size at this time.
  target_range.setValues(values);
}
```

I have created this function for my google sheet, however, it updates the same 20 rows. What I need it to do is update the rows, then I have a clear function that clears one spreadsheet, then adding another 20 rows under the first 20 rows and so on, sort of having an append row function for 20 rows at a time.

However, any code I am trying is not working.

The Code I have so far is this attached.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your code always updates the same 20 rows. The reason is found in this line: 
`target_sheet.getRange(2,1,values.length,values[19].length)`

Your target range **ALWAYS** starts on row#2, so it will overwrite anything that already exists on row#2 and below. Instead you want the data to be copied to the row following the "LastRow" (whatever that may be).

Try this:

```
var targetLR = target.getLastRow();
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(targetLR+1,1,values.length,values[19].length);
```

Two changes here:

1. `getLastRow()` returns the position of the last row that has content.
2. So we just add "1" to this value ("targetLR+1") to define the start of the target_range on the following line.